# adding .net framework 4.5 or later to my vs 2017

Tags: asmx, .net-framework-version, target-framework

months ago I was using vs 2019 to create my apps including web applications. I used to publish them on my localhost and servers and I had no problem. then I had to downgrade to vs 2017 and i'm facing a lot of troubles. I created an asmx webservice and tried to publish it on my iis server but i'm getting this error: "The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file." I opened my web.config file but there's no targetframework attribute in the compilation tag:

```
<compilation debug="true" >
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
```

I removed the "Version=3.5.0.0" attribute from all the tags but still the same. so I tried to change my target framework in vs but the highest version found in it is .NET framework 3.5. I tried installing version 4.5 but I got a message telling me that I already have this version or higher on my machine so it can't be installed. now what should I do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 - how to change .NET version of existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399323/visual-studio-2017-how-to-change-net-version-of-existing-project)

Comment: yes but the highest version in the properties is 3.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399809/11683

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll check the links right now